# How does Youtube's HTML5 video player control buffering?

Tags: html, video, youtube

I was watching a youtube video and I decided to investigate some parts of its video player.  I noticed that unlike most HTML5 video I have seen, Youtube's video player does not do a normal video source and instead utilizes a blob url as the source.

Previously I have tested HTML5 videos and I found that the server starts streaming the whole video from  the start and buffers in the background the complete rest of the video.  This means that if your video is 300 megs, all 300 megs will be downloaded.  If you seek to the middle, it will start downloading from the seek position all the way to the end.

Youtube does not work this way (at least in chrome).  Instead it manages to control buffering so it only buffers a certain amount while paused. It also seems to only buffer the relevant pieces, so if you skip around it will make sure not to buffer pieces that are unlikely to be watched.

In my attempts to investigate how this worked, I noticed the video src tag has a value of `blob:http%3A//www.youtube.com/ee625eee-2802-49b2-a13f-eb374d551d54`, which pointed me to [blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), which then led me to [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).  Using those two resources I am able to load a mp4 video into a blob and display it in a HTML5 video tag.

However, what I am now stuck on is how Youtube deals with the pieces.  Looking at the network traffic it appears to sends requests to `http://r6---sn-p5q7ynee.c.youtube.com/videoplayback` which returns binary video data back in chunks of 1.1mb.  It also seems worth noting that most normal requests due to HTML5 video requests seem to receive a 206 response code back while it streams, yet youtube's playvideo calls get a 200 back.

I tried to attempt to only load a range of bytes (via setting the `Range` http header) which unfortunately failed (I'm assuming because there was no meta-data for the video coming with the video).

At this point I'm stuck on figuring out how Youtube accomplishes this.  I came up with several ideas though none of which I am completely sold on:

1) Youtube is sending down self contained video and audio chunks with each `/videoplayback` call.  This seems like a pretty heavy burden on the upload side and it seems like it would be difficult to stitch these together to make it appear like it's one seemless video.  Also, the video tag seems to think it's one full video, judging from calling `$('video').duration` and `$('video').currentTime`, which leads me to believe that the video tag thinks it's a single video file.  Finally, the vidoe src tag never changes which makes me believe it is working with a singular blob and not switching out blobs.

2) Youtube constructs an empty blob pre-sized to the full video array and updates the blob with pieces as it downloads it.  It would then make sure the user has not gotten too close to the last downloaded piece (to prevent the user from entering an undownloaded section of the blob).  The problem that I see with this that I don't see any way to dynamically update a blob through javascript (although maybe I'm just having trouble googling for it)

3) Youtube downloads the meta data and then starts constructing the blob in order by appending the video pieces as it downloads them.  The problem I see with this method is I don't understand how it would handle seeks in post-buffered territory.

Maybe I"m just missing an obvious answer that's right in front of me.  Anyone have any ideas?

---

edit: I just thought of a fourth option.  Another idea is they might use the file API to write the binary chunks to a file and use that file to stream off of.  The file API seems to have the ability to seek to specific positions, therefore allowing you to fill a video with empty bytes and fill them in as they are received.  This would definitely accommodate video seeking as well.

Comment: I thought they used [MediaStream API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_API) but so far I've been too lazy to fully investigate. Please do and let me know! =)

Comment: Different from the [MediaSource API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API)....

Comment: Interesting API, though it lacks quite a few things that would be needed (like a way to start), unless i'm reading things incorrectly.  Either way I do not work at the company I was working at where I was conducting this research for and don't know when I'd get back to this type of stuff :)

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right and it's not compatible. I didn't fully investigate. If you won't either, I'll keep it on the TODO.

Comment: @KallDrexx did you find out  anything since the post was written?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so few things you need to know is that YouTube is based on this great open source [Project](https://github.com/google/shaka-player). It behaves different for every browser and if your browser supports more intensive decoding like WEBM it will use that to save Google's bandwidth.  Also if you look at this [Demo](http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/)
 Then you will find a section which downloads the entire video into a thing called "offline storage". I know chrome has it and some other browsers not every in some cases they do have to use the entire video source instead of a blob. So that blob is streaming depending on the user interaction with the video. Yes the video is just 1 file and they have metadata for that video like a little database that tells the time of the video and the points at which chunks can be divided in.

You can find out more by reading the Project's documentation. I really recommend you have a look at the demo.

Answer (score 5):

When you look at the AppData of GoogleChrome, while playing a youtube video, you will see that it buffers in segmented files. The videos uploaded to youtube are segmented, which is why you can't perfectly pinpoint a timeframe in the first click on the bar if that timeframe is outside of the current segment.

The amount of segments depends on the length of the video, and the time from which you start and stop playing back the video.

When you are linked to a timeframe of a video, it will simply skip the buffering of the segments that come before that timeframe.

Unfortunately I don't know much about the coding for video playback, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Interesting, I do see a multitude of files being added to my AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache directory, and judging from the network traffic the 1.1MB files are the video chunks.  Now the question remains on how they stitch them together.   Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

there is a canvas element in the page ,Maybe This Will Help
http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

we knew the video is been segmented,the question is how to stitch them together.i think the real video element doesn't do the play work,it support the datasource,and draw the seagments each frame to the canvas element。

```
var v = document.getElementById('v'); 
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
v.addEventListener('play', function(){ 
   if(v.paused || v.ended) return false; 
   c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h); 
   setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h); 
},false);
```

---

Comment: Please explain your answer some more (perhaps by adding some information from the link you provided). Link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: sorry,my english is poor。we knew the video is been segmented,the question is how to stitch them together.i think the real video element doesn't do the play work,it support the datasource,and draw the seagments each frame to the canvas element...

Answer (score 3):

Youtube is using this feature only in browsers that support Media Source Extensions so it is up to the browser decide about all the rest because of this feature.