# How youtube load video source via xhr

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have seen http requests via chrome. And I found that Youtube's video element use "blob:https://www.youtube.com/80573d69-e6c1-4c74-b3ac-62a2627c978c".

[image]

And it sent so many XHR requests to get video resource (video/webm).

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that's the video stream? Those response sizes seem a little small to me.

Comment: It is worth reading the thoughts in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238471/how-does-youtubes-html5-video-player-control-buffering